# Create a grid with combo box in cells

Tags: support, mockups

In the UI wireframe designer, is it possible to create a data grid with combo boxes inside the cells?

Comment: You're talking about the Balsamiq wireframes tool you can use when asking/answering questions on this site, right?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Didn't realize it had a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a feature this appears to be [planned but low-priority for Balsamiq](http://community.balsamiq.com/balsamiq/topics/combobox_inside_a_datagrid?utm_medium=widget&utm_source=widget_balsamiq&from_gsfn=true) (Balsamiq makes the software, we just have a plugin to let us use it). You can click the +1 to like the suggestion to show support for the feature.

As a quick and dirty solution, you can just layer comboboxes on top of a datagrid:

[image]

Use the "bring to top" layering item to make sure the combos are on top (they should automatically appear as the top item as you add them though) and you can sit them over table cells. Since ultimately what people on the site see are images of the wireframe anyway, the end result isn't that different from a more proper implimentation.